# How can I validate http response headers?

Tags: validation, http-headers

It's the first time I am doing something with headers. I am mainly concerned with Cache-Control but there may be others I will need to check as well. For example, I try to send the following header to the browser (based on tutorials I just read):

```
Cache-Control:private, max-age=2011-12-30 11:40:56
```

Google Chrome displays it this way in Network -> Headers -> Response headers, but how do I know if it's correct, that there aren't any typos, syntax errors and such? Will it really work? Will the browser behave like I want it to, or will it treat it like a gibberish (something like "unknown header/value")? I've tried sending nonsensical headers on purpose but they got displayed with the rest. Is there any Chrome tool / addon for that, or any other way? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to check if the resource has been cached by proxies en route, but you can check if your browser has cached it.

While in the Network panel of Chrome DevTools, hit F5 to reload your page. You should see something like "304 Not Modified" in the status field for the resource you are treating (which means the resource has not been modified and its contents were not received from the server but rather loaded from the browser's cache.)